# Hapi, good ald logstash: how to prevent crashes?

Tags: hapi.js, hapi-good

I have a `Hapi` installation which uses `good` as a logging plugin and `good-logstash-tcp` extension to send logs to `logstash`.

My current problem is that `logstash` server may sometimes be unavailable, and that currently causes the whole server to crash with an error like the following:

```
/.../node_modules/good-logstash-tcp/lib/logstash.js:178
            self.emit('error', new Error('Max retries reached, transport in silent mode, OFFLINE'));
                               ^
Error: Max retries reached, transport in silent mode, OFFLINE
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/good-logstash-tcp/lib/logstash.js:178:36)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:511:12)
```

Is there an easy way to make `Hapi` keep on running even if logging fails for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Use an utility like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to automatically restart your Node application after an error.

Example with nodemon:

1) Install it with `npm install -g nodemon`

2) Run your app with `nodemon index.js` instead of `node index.js` or `npm start`

Comment: But it will not start properly if `logstash` is still offline.